# EXCEL double IF statement with VLOOKUP - Handing Error on second IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

Basically, I have a double IF statement to check whether a certain value exists within the first list and if it's false then check a second list. Then if the value doesn't exists in the second list then I should know that the value doesn't exists in either list.

However, I'm having trouble with understanding in the particular scenario that the value doesn't exists in both list, why does my second false statement not work? I get #N/A for the value of 11.

I know I could use IFERROR, but I wanted to know the thought process of why it doesn't work!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNTIF` or `COUNTIFS` would be easier here:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$6,A2)+COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$17,A2)>0,"FOUND","NOT FOUND")
```

[image]

Or `MATCH` and `ISNUMBER`.

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$6,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,$F$2:$F$17,0))),"FOUND","NOT FOUND")
```

[image]

In your `VLOOKUP` approach, the *first* `VLOOKUP` failing is what causing the entire formula to return `#N/A`, as you can verify by using Formulas > Evaluate Formula. You would need to handle an error being thrown by either `VLOOKUP`. Nesting an `IF` doesn't circumvent this.

Comment: this is a shorter list just to ask my question. But the first list is over 1M rows so I was using the double vlookup technique with sorted lists cause it is apparently faster.

Comment: Well you'd have to handle the possibility of either `VLOOKUP` throwing an error. That's the original issue. You could also use `MATCH`.

Comment: ahhhh ok that make sense. That's what I was missing in failing to handle either vlookup throwing an error! Thanks!

Comment: @JVMaverick if this answer helped, please, mark it as correct, so the question can be closed